# Writing header only the first time through looping pages

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have some code that loops through different pages and writes the results to a csv file. Every page consists of the header row and 250 rows of data. The problem is I only want the header row to print on the first page, yet the header prints with every page.  Right now I have the header set to False.  I'm trying to code it to say something like. If page==1, then header= true else header= false.  I don't know how to code it or where to code it.  Can somehow show me how to do it?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

def stock_data(stock_info):
    data = pd.DataFrame(stock_info)
    data = data.iloc[:, 4:]
    data.to_csv("data.csv", mode='a',index=False)


url = "https://www.stockrover.com/stock_infos/grid?_dc=1644876887410"

payload = "state=%7B%22sortInfo%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22columns%22%3A%5B76%2C77%2C50%2C80%2C547%2C13%2C21%2C771%5D%2C%22view%22%3A313%2C%22priorPrimaryColumn%22%3A170%2C%22filterData%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22name%22%3A%22New%201%22%2C%22cType%22%3A%22Screener%22%2C%22cNode%22%3A%22s_42%22%2C%22cIsFolder%22%3Afalse%2C%22gridSelection%22%3A%22ANDE%22%2C%22lastActive%22%3A1396898415%2C%22primaryColumn%22%3A76%2C%22folderDisabledParams%22%3A%7B%22filterData%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%2C%22mainGridDateRange%22%3A%22ytd%22%2C%22groupState%22%3Anull%2C%22moversGridDateRange%22%3A%221_day%22%2C%22peersGridDateRange%22%3A%221_day%22%2C%22lastGridSelections%22%3A%5B%22ANDE%22%5D%2C%22lastQuantNode%22%3A%5B%22s_42%22%2C%22s_42%22%5D%2C%22includeQuotesInTable%22%3Afalse%2C%22includeAllQuotesLastValue%22%3Afalse%2C%22markets%22%3A%7B%22panel%22%3A%22summary%22%7D%2C%22researchPanel%22%3A%22comparisonPanel%22%2C%22recentSearchTickers%22%3A%5B%22SPY%22%2C%22AMZN%22%2C%22AAPL%22%2C%22s_32%22%2C%22%5ENDX%22%2C%22AXP%22%2C%22XOM%22%2C%22AFL%22%2C%22%5EDJX%22%2C%22AIT%22%2C%22ADVC%22%5D%2C%22quotesBoxTickers%22%3A%5B%22AMZN%22%2C%22AAPL%22%2C%22SPY%22%5D%2C%22checkedQuotesBoxTickers%22%3A%5B%22AMZN%22%2C%22AAPL%22%2C%22SPY%22%5D%2C%22dashboard%22%3A%7B%22buttonRef%22%3A%22272%22%7D%2C%22tickerSelectedFeeds%22%3A%5B%22Benzinga%20News%22%2C%22Yahoo%20News%22%5D%2C%22marketSelectedFeeds%22%3A%5B%22Google%20News%22%2C%22Stock%20Market%20News%20-%20Investing.com%22%5D%2C%22bondsSelectedFeeds%22%3A%5B%22Bonds%20Strategy%20-%20Investing.com%22%5D%2C%22commoditiesSelectedFeeds%22%3A%5B%22Commodities%20%26%20Futures%20News%20-%20Investing.com%22%2C%22Commodities%20Fundamental%20Analysis%20-%20Investing.com%22%2C%22Commodities%20Strategy%20Analysis%20-%20Investing.com%22%5D%2C%22stocksSelectedFeeds%22%3A%5B%22CNNMoney%20News%22%2C%22Google%20News%22%2C%22Seeking%20Alpha%20Top%20Stories%22%5D%2C%22etfsSelectedFeeds%22%3A%5B%22Economy%20News%20-%20Investing.com%22%2C%22ETF%20Analysis%20-%20Investing.com%22%2C%22Investing%20Ideas%20-%20Investing.com%22%5D%2C%22topPanel%22%3A%22researchPanel%22%2C%22maxRecordsNode%22%3Afalse%2C%22version%22%3A7%2C%22lastGridSelectionsRaw%22%3A%5B%22ANDE%22%5D%2C%22lastSelectionScreeners%22%3A%22s_42%22%2C%22quotesDisabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22lastSelectionPortfolios%22%3A%22p_2%22%2C%22comparisonPanels%22%3A%7B%22Portfolio%22%3A%22p_2%22%2C%22Index%22%3A%22%5EDJX%22%2C%22Watchlist%22%3A%22Watchlists%22%2C%22Screener%22%3A%22s_42%22%7D%2C%22lastSelectionWatchlists%22%3A%22w_26%22%2C%22indicesSelectedFeeds%22%3A%5B%22Google%20News%22%2C%22Yahoo%20News%22%5D%2C%22newsActive%22%3A%22tickerNews%22%2C%22recentSearchMetrics%22%3A%5B%22Price%22%2C%22EPS%22%2C%22Sales%22%5D%2C%22editPanel%22%3A%22positionsPanel%22%2C%22newsType%22%3A%22marketNews%22%2C%22tableColumns%22%3A%5B%22ticker%22%2C%22rank%22%2C%22score_rank%22%2C%22filter_score%22%2C%22company%22%2C%22cash%22%2C%22currentassets%22%2C%22netppe%22%2C%22intangibles%22%2C%22totalassets%22%2C%22currentliabilities%22%2C%22longtermdebt%22%2C%22totaldebt%22%2C%22totalliabilities%22%2C%22equity%22%2C%22tangiblebookvalue%22%2C%22cash_short_term_p%22%2C%22net_ppe_p%22%2C%22intangibles_p%22%5D%2C%22last_save%22%3A1644837064%2C%22panels%22%3A%7B%22collapsed%22%3A%7B%22chp%22%3Atrue%2C%22ip%22%3Atrue%2C%22mp%22%3Afalse%2C%22qp%22%3Afalse%2C%22conp%22%3Atrue%2C%22fsp%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22viewportWidth%22%3A%221920%22%2C%22viewportHeight%22%3A%221069%22%2C%22chartPanelHeight%22%3A483%2C%22controlPanelWidth%22%3A296%2C%22insightPanelWidth%22%3A%22485%22%2C%22quoteBoxHeight%22%3A200%2C%22navigationPanelWidth%22%3A277%7D%7D&updateMarket=true&page={}&start={}&limit={}"

headers = {
  'authority': 'www.stockrover.com',
  'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="98", "Google Chrome";v="98"',
  'x-csrf-token': 'fAeVScD26lby5MQf5YFI5p3snudo3E+rw0TL0h1W3j/vcjsIMvgxAF5Z9DkMjjCU4trT/b4EV0VCCPvmms5VIw==',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.82 Safari/537.36',
  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
  'accept': 'application/json',
  'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
  'origin': 'https://www.stockrover.com',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  'referer': 'https://www.stockrover.com/research/all/313/s_42/ANDE',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
  'cookie': 'remember_me_pref=0; user_name=test11964; plan=3; premiumBraintreeKey=MIIBCgKCAQEAzM4LJfrNnBOgRFB1dDJkmqTFCWT2Y%2BksOydD8xDH4R033WUzxbffMZb%2B3dqEyQvOVjLcwFIHByDc4Xwej7enas2E%2FVRyh7Cvyadn7M5zQeRyLcI9Ys5KCozMwxJPc0x76FlXPwiAo1Qlz3RcLb9wGHBag2R51FuTie%2BhVDCgzWajqDCREzRhi%2Fqlt3D%2FxXNo%2FiwJlpOUr%2Fx1QnkkILxgKlq1dD7KJ767O5ojYKXsO%2BV2Bfu7sSD3djsOxQJ1%2FRbaDm2E96EDkWhhOeOpPndQ6IuSl4NmnJg%2Fcq6f8csW8M3Ys%2BMZPFkdxPC4%2FfRM1XC9o76PjpVNBIO%2ByJEELKZedwIDAQAB; lr=1644876886; _Ruby2_session=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%3D--b963330daa985315420ea5893f1cfa3e3a54c9d5; _Ruby2_session=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--a126f3bcc5b8af0a5a824e6b674d55f1fe9ee12e; lr=1644876939'
}

 
for page in range(3):
    pld = payload.format(page+1, page*250, 250)
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=pld)
    stock_info = response.json()['stock_infos']
    stock_data(stock_info)
```

Comment: Would you consider appending the results of stock_info into a list within each iteration, then once the loop is over converting this list into a dataframe?

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to do that though.

Comment: Please see the snippet in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append the stock_info block into a list

```
stocklist=[]
for page in range(3):
    pld = payload.format(page+1, page*250, 250)
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=pld)
    stock_info = response.json()['stock_infos']
    stocklist.append(stock_info)
```

Then flatten the list (because we created a list of lists) - see [the explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

```
flattened = [item for sublist in stocklist for item in sublist]
```

And finally, call your function to convert this into a dataframe and subsequently a csv

```
stock_data(flattened)
```

Comment: That's just terrific, exactly what I wanted.  Thank you very much!!!!!